# jQuery better way for my colors app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm a newbies in jQuery and i must confess that i dont like it!

I looking for everywhere for informations and this is what i did with my little skills!

I confess that my code work but rather badly, and i doubt it is optimized. 
Could you help me to improve & optimize this jQuery code please!

As you can see, the code is designed to display various informations in several tag (div, li, h2 ...) when the user select one of these colors.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("div.color-value.hex p").text("pick a color");
$("div.color-value.rgba p").text("pick a color");
$("div.color-value.hsla p").text("pick a color");

$("ul.color-list li").click(function() {

    //var value;

    switch ( $("ul.color-list.one li").index(this) ) {
        case 0 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#1E2224");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla");
            break;
        case 1 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#2");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba2");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla2");
            break;
        case 2 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color without alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#3");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba3");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla3");
            break;
        case 3 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("simple color");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#4");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba4");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla4");
            break;
        case 4 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#5");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba5");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla5");
            break;
        case 5 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#6");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba6");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla6");
            break;

        case 6 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#7");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba7");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla7");
            break;
        }

    // second swatch
    switch ( $("ul.color-list.two li").index(this) ) {
        case 0 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#1E2224");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla");
            break;
        case 1 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#2");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba2");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla2");
            break;
        case 2 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#3");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba3");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla3");
            break;
        case 3 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#4");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba4");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla4");
            break;
        case 4 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#5");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba5");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla5");
            break;
        case 5 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#6");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba6");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla6");
            break;

        case 6 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#7");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba7");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla7");
            break;
        }


    // third swatches
    switch ( $("ul.color-list.three li").index(this) ) {
        case 0 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#1E2224");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla");
            break;
        case 1 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#2");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba2");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla2");
            break;
        case 2 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#3");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba3");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla3");
            break;
        case 3 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#4");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba4");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla4");
            break;
        case 4 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#5");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba5");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla5");
            break;
        case 5 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#6");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba6");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla6");
            break;

        case 6 :
            $(this).addClass("ckd");
            $("div.color-type-infos").text("color with alpha");
            $("div.color-value.hex p").text("#7");
            $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("#rgba7");
            $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("#hsla7");
            break;
        }
    });

    $("ul.color-list li").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("ckd")){
                $(this).removeClass("ckd");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("ckd");
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what you're trying to achieve exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times there is no need to use `switch` statements, you can store the info in  `data-*` attributes and read it using `.data()` method:

```
<li  ... data-info="the info body"></li>
```

For toggling the classes you can use `.toggleClass()` method so using the second click handler is not necessary, you could also move it's body to your first handler, I haven't seen the markup but according to your code something like the following should help to minify the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $hex = $("div.color-value.hex p").text("pick a color"),
        $rgba = $("div.color-value.rgba p").text("pick a color"),
        $hsla = $("div.color-value.hsla p").text("pick a color"),
        $info = $("div.color-type-infos");

    $("ul.color-list li").on('click', function() {
        var i = $("ul.color-list.one li").index(this) + 1;
        $("ul.color-list li").not(this).removeClass('ckd');
        var info = $(this).toggleClass("ckd").data('info');

        $info.text(info);
        $hex.text( "#" + (i === 1 ? "1E2224" : i) );
        $rgba.text( "#rgba" + (i !== 1 ? i : "") );
        $hsla.text( "#hsla" + (i !== 1 ? i : "") );
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i obtain SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!=='

Comment: @GilbertOOl Yes, sorry, I had missed the first operand, `i`, updated the answer.

Comment: Just an little problem, if an "ul.color-list.one li" is clicked and have "ckd" class, i would like if another "ul.color-list.one li" is clicked "ckd" class disappear without clicking it a second time!